# How to create variable names that are concatenated with a increasing number

Tags: lua, variable-names

I am currently programming a Lua script. There I would like to have a variable name which is concatenated with an increasing number.

Example: Q0001,Q0002,Q0003,...,Q9999

My following script for this is:

```
local rnd = math.random (0,9999)
local Text = ""
print(rnd)
if rnd > 0 and rnd < 10 then
    --Add Nulls before Number and the "Q"
    Text = Q000 .. rnd
elseif rnd >= 10 and rnd < 100 then
    --Add Nulls before Number and the "Q"
    Text = Q00 .. rnd
elseif rnd >= 100 and rnd < 1000 then
    --Add Null before Number and the "Q"
    Text = Q0 .. rnd
elseif rnd >= 1000 then
    --Add "Q"
    Text = Q .. rnd
end
print(Text)
```

Logically I put this into a function, because its only a part of my programm. Later in the programm I like to get informations with the variable, because the product of the variable `Q###` is a table which I have programmed. My second thought to solve the problem was to convert it as a text, but then I don't know how to convert this into a declaration.

Edit 04/04/15 19:17: Too make it more clear. I want that Text stands after the end of the script for a table I set before. So that I can say `Text.Name` e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.format` with padded format specifiers:

Just a single line:

```
Text = ("Q%04d"):format( rnd )
-- same as Text = string.format( "Q%04d", rnd )
```

Instead of creating so many tables, use a single table with the above values as keys/indexes:

```
t = {
    Q0001 = "something",
    Q0002 = "something",
    Q0013 = "something",
    Q0495 = "something",
    -- so on
}
```

Comment: Or just use a plain array.

Comment: Ok, I googled the string.format function, but there is only a list with the argruments. So I don't really understand what you have explained to me here. And after I tested your example in the console the name Q### was given out, but there should be nil because i haven't declareted the Variable yet. And I get the following Error:

Comment: org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: C:\...'FileName'.lua:46 table index expected, got table
stack traceback:
 C:\...'FileName'.lua:46: in main chunk
 [Java]: in ?
 at org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue.typerror(Unknown Source)
 at org.luaj.vm2.LuaTable.set(Unknown Source)
 at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.execute(Unknown Source)
 at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.onInvoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at lua.processScript(Unknown Source)
 at lua.main(Unknown Source)